# How do I efficiently pre-pend a line to a large file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have some large files in CSV format that I would like to turn into objects using the `Import-Csv` command in Powershell.  The files are missing the column headings however and these need to be added before I use `Import-Csv`.  What is the fastest and most efficient way of adding these to the file?

Answer (score 6):

Prepending to a large file is not an easy or quick operation.

However, import-csv does have a "header" argument that you can use to specify the column headers, i.e.:

```
$header = 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'
import-csv .\myfile.csv -header $header
```

Comment: I think the -header argument is only available in PowerShell V2.

Answer (score 5):

This one liner works nicely.

```
 @("Header Text") + (get-content myFile.txt) | set-content myFile.txt
```

Explanation

- `@("Header Text")` creates an array with one item.
- `+ (get-content myFile.txt)` creates a new array with the contents of both.
- `| set-content myFile.txt` pipes the result to set-content and saves to file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there is a way to do this in one line, but this will work.

Assuming you have *Test.csv* with these contents:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

This PowerShell code will create a new file, *NewTest.csv*, with column names and append the contents of Test.csv.

```
Add-Content -path .\NewTest.csv -value "Col1,Col2,Col3"
$contents = Get-Content .\Test.csv
Add-Content -path .\NewTest.csv -value $contents
```

I can't speak to the performance of this if you have a really large file, but I'm not aware of any other way to do this.

Comment: To speed things up a bit, pipe the Get-Content to Add-Content: Get-Content .\Test.csv | Add-Content -path .\NewTest.csv

Answer (score 0):

Copy the string you want to prepend to a new file then concatenate the rest to that new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$largeFile = get-content .\largeFile.txt
$header = "Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4"
$headerArray = $header -split ' '
$headerArray + $largeFile | out-file largeFileWithHeader.txt
```